# "Cannot invoke "java.lang.CharSequence.toString()" because "replacement" is null"

Tags: java, scala, tostring, gatling

I am building a body for a request which is a string (in JSON format). The final character of "$studentRefIdList" should be ignored since it is an unwanted ",".
The following code produces the desired string:

```
String[] studentsArr = studentsList.split(",");

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for(String i: studentsArr){
            builder.append("{\"studentPersonalRefId\":\"" + i + "\"},");
        }

String body = parsedString.replace("\"$studentRefIdList\"", builder.substring(0, builder.toString().length() - 1))
                .replace("$title", title)
                .replace("$teacherRefId", session.getString("userRefId"))
                .replace("$sectionId", session.getString("sectionRefId"))
                .replace("$sif_RefObject", session.getString("assignmentType"))
                .replace("$availableDate", availableDate)
                .replace("$dueDate", dueDate);

  return body;
```

However, when I make a request to the associated endpoint  I get this error:
**"Cannot invoke "java.lang.CharSequence.toString()" because "replacement" is null"**

I understand that this is a Java error relating to toString() but I couldn't find a similar question.

For context, this is the original scala version of this code :

```
    val body = parsedString.replace("\"$studentRefIdList\"", builder.toString().dropRight(1))
      .replace("$title", title)
      .replace("$teacherRefId", session("teacherRefId").as[String])
      .replace("$sectionId", session("sectionRefId").as[String])
      .replace("$sif_RefObject", session("assignmentType").as[String])
      .replace("$availableDate", availableDate)
      .replace("$dueDate", dueDate)
    body
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you *want* to get as result when one of value is null? (I am not Scala dev so don't know how `session("teacherRefId").as[String]` handles nulls). If you simply want to replace it with `null` *String* you could wrap your session values with `String.valueOf(..)` like `String.valueOf(session.getString("userRefId"))` which in case of `null` will produce `"null"` String.